# How to use VueJS plugins directly in the browser?

Tags: jquery, module, vue.js, vue-tables-2

I am including VueJS as a replacement for JQuery in a legacy system, but I have encountered problems in being able to use plugins, as I would with JQuery.
To give an example, the "vuetable" library indicates that it can be imported directly into the html using script tags, but I can not make it work:

I import the scripts

```
<div id="app">
<vuetable
        api-url="/api/users"
        :fields="columns">
</vuetable>
</div>

<script src="js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="js/vue-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/vue-table.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

then, inside my file JS I try to manipulate the information.

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            columns: [
                'firstname',
                'lastname',
                'nickname',
                'birthdate',
                'group.name_en',
                'gender',
                'last_login',
            ]
        },
methods: {CODE}
    })
</script>
```

Inside, I get the information by `fetch()` and then I pass it to the component by means of its props. When I try intonoces, invoking the component by its label I get an error saying that vueetables is not defined: `app.js Uncaught ReferenceError: Vuetable is not defined`

Comment: You should not have script tags in an external JS file

Comment: I tried with these - did not work when I created a [mcve] - possibly the wrong vue-table `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.3.4/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-table@0.2.2/dist/index.common.min.js"></script>

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all that's missing is a couple of `Vue.use()` statements at the top of your script.

Also note, for Vue2 use [vuetable-2](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2)

```js
console.clear()
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(Vuetable)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    columns: ['name', 'email','birthdate','nickname','gender']
  },
  methods: {}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.5"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetable-2@1.6.0"></script>

<div id="app">
<vuetable ref="vuetable"
  api-url="https://vuetable.ratiw.net/api/users"
  :fields="columns"
  pagination-path="">
</vuetable>
</div>
```